# rails nested resource unknown attribute error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested

I have a Contract and a Task_Order model. I keep getting an `unknown attribute error for contract_id` Each `Contract has many Task Orders`. I have read other nested models unknown attribute error questions but they haven't been able to help me. Please keep in mind I am pretty new to Rails and would greatly appreciate any help I can get. I am using **`Rails 4.0`**

Contract Model:

```
has_many :task_orders
```

Contract schema:

```
create_table "contracts", force: true do |t|
   t.string   "contractId"
   t.string   "contractName"
 end
```

Task Order Model:

```
belongs_to :contracts
```

Task Order Schema:

```
create_table "task_orders", force: true do |t|
t.string   "contract_Id"
t.string   "task_orderId"
t.string   "task_orderName"
end
```

When I click `Show Contract`, I get the error:

```
unknown attribute: contract_id
```

This is the line that gets highlighted:

```
<%= form_for([@contract, @contract.task_orders.new]) do |f| %>
```

I can tell that Rails is trying to print out `contract_id`, which is not in my `Contract` model... so how can I get it to print out `contractId` instead - which is in my `Contract` model?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something you need to be aware of is the [`foreign_key`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) of Rails (and relational databases in general):

---

**Foreign Key**

Rails' standard `foreign_key` is to use [`snake_case`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) (`contract_id`), however, you *can* use non-conventional `foreign_keys` like this:

```
#app/models/order.rb
belongs_to :contract, foreign_key: "contract_Id"

#schema SHOULD be:
create_table "orders", force: true do |t|
   t.integer "contract_id" #-> should
   t.string "contract_Id" #-> your current
end
```

---

**Primary Key**

```
create_table "contracts", force: true do |t|
   t.string   "contractId" #-> don't need

   t.string   "contractName" #-> your current
   t.string "name" #-> should be
 end
```

Your [`primary_key`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) is almost always going to be the `id` column. You should remove your `contractId` column from the `contracts` db!

---

[**Task Orders**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

You'll need to do this:

```
#app/models/order.rb
belongs_to :contracts
has_many :task_orders
```

You'll then need another model at `app/models/task_order.rb`

---

**Form**

Your form is showing the error. This is because you're trying to create an ActiveRecord in the view itself. You'll be much better using the standard [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) method of passing nested model data through a form:

```
#app/models/contract.rb
def new
    @contract = Contract.new
    @contract.task_orders.build
end

#app/views/contracts/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @contract do |f| %>
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for the insight. I made my contract_Id field a string because I need it to be a string, not an integer. Is there any way around this?

Comment: If it's an `id` surely it will be an `integer`?? Why do you need it to be a `string`?

Comment: For example, I have a contract id called "COPD-2340" which is a string, not an integer...

Comment: Okay I am sorry! Should have considered that a bit more :D

Answer (score 2):

Task Order Model should have this line `belongs_to contract`

[**belongs_to**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) association should be declared as a singular of corresponding model

Also there should be **contract_id** column within **task_orders** table.

Diagram below explains default behavior of belongs_to in Rails

[image]

Comment: Hi - I tried but, I am still getting the same error... @cvibha

Comment: I want to know that why do task_order schema does not has `contract_id` instead of `t.string "contract_Id`. By default if you have `belongs_to model_name` in your model then there should be `model_name_id` column with `type as integer` in that table

Comment: Hi - in my Contract model I have t.string "contractId" and in my Task Order model I have t.string "contract_Id" @cvibha

Comment: Hi, Can you add a column **contract_id** in your task_orders table with type integer

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,use **`singular names`** for `belongs_to`

```
Class TaskOrder < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :contract

end
```

Secondly,try changing your `contract_Id` in your `task_orders` table to `contract_id`.

Rails by default look for `model_name_id(in your case contract_id)` `foreign key` unless if any of the `custom foreign keys` defined in your model.

And finally,specify the `data type integer` for `default foreign key`.In your case it should be `t.integer contract_id`

However if you want `contract_Id` as `foreign key`,you should define it as `custom foreign key` in the `Contract` model itself like this

```
Class Contract < ActiveRecord:Base

has_many :task_orders,:foreign_key => "contract_Id"

end
```